# Excel Pivot Table - Calculate % of Row Total Without Showing All Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Is there any way to show % of a row, without displaying all the columns of a pivot table? I know how to show % of a row from count using Show Values As -> % of Parent Row Total, but I don't want to display all columns.

e.g.

```
Class   | Assignments On Time
--------|-------------------
Math    | 70%
English | 50%
```

In this case, there are two columns: Assignments On Time and Assignments Late. But I'm only showing Assignments On Time.

I can do this by hiding a column, but there's got to be a better solution.